# Возможно ли заразиться вирусом на сайте

Tags: вирусы

Теоретически, можно ли при посещении веб-страниц не скачивая никаких файлов поймать вирус, который может навредить ОС? Например, Windows.

Comment: Можно . . . . .

Comment: Флеш - главная дыра, но, не единственная.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

При посещении веб-страниц вы все же скачиваете кучу файлов в temporary, так что если на сайте используется вредоносный js с client-side выполнением, то очень даже может.

Comment: Да-да, вот я про это и хотел узнать. В JS такое возможно сделать, да?

Comment: может, но поскольку js напрямую просто так не станет работать с файловой системой, если его руками на запустить из нее, скорее всего максимум он сможет "нахулиганить" внутри браузера, как песочницы.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас это довольно тяжело но возможно, есть несколько вариантов.

1. Уязвимости браузера
2. Уязвимости плагинов для браузера
3. Встроенный вредоносный скрипт

Думаю есть еще варианты